# Rename Files and Directories (Add Prefix)

Tags: language-agnostic

I would like to add prefix on all folders and directories.

Example:

I have

```
Hi.jpg
1.txt
folder/
this.file_is.here.png
another_folder.ok/
```

I would like to add prefix "PRE_"

```
PRE_Hi.jpg
PRE_1.txt
PRE_folder/
PRE_this.file_is.here.png
PRE_another_folder.ok/
```

Comment: Use AWK as on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099492/9874050) answer: awk '$0="prefix"$0' file > new_file

Answer (score 319):

Thanks to [Peter van der Heijden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31799/peter-van-der-heijden), here's one that'll work for filenames with spaces in them:

```
for f in * ; do mv -- "$f" "PRE_$f" ; done
```

*("--" is needed to succeed with files that begin with dashes, whose names would otherwise be interpreted as switches for the mv command)*

Comment: Heh, true, this will completely not work if you have a file with a space in it.

Comment: If you change the `ls` command to `*` and put double quotes around the arguments to `mv`, it will work for files containing spaces.

Comment: @CanSpice Is it possible to reverse this operation (remove the prefix) with a similar script?

Comment: It's OK, here is the solution for my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10536148/492638

Comment: Thanks, mate. The intern here was loosing his finger caps renaming all 67 files. Cheers.

Comment: Is there a way to remove a common prefix?

Comment: It should be "mv --" not just "mv", to guard against files starting with dashes, that would otherwise be interpreted as command switches. I will contribute an edit to correct this.

Comment: This working well in `bash`, how can I do this in `tcsh`

Answer (score 110):

Use [the *rename* script](http://training.perl.com/scripts/rename) this way:

```
$ rename 's/^/PRE_/' *
```

There are no problems with metacharacters or whitespace in filenames.

Comment: Some systems have a util-linux utility called "rename" which works differently (on Ubuntu it's called "rename.ul").

Comment: `rename` has always helped me handle multiple file renames very easily.

Comment: Had issue with @ symbol in prefix. Needed to \@ but that was easy.  Worked well.

Answer (score 84):

For **adding prefix or suffix** for files(directories), you could use the simple and powerful way by **xargs**:

```
ls | xargs -I {} mv {} PRE_{}

ls | xargs -I {} mv {} {}_SUF
```

It is using the paramerter-replacing option of xargs: -I. And you can get more detail from the man page.

Comment: P.S.: If you just want to **rename part files** (directories) of current directory, just filter it before xargs, such as: `ls *.old | xargs -I {} mv {} PRE_{}`

Comment: interestingly using rename did not work. using xargs went well for my RHEL setup so +1 for this option, makes it easy to understand the command

Comment: Doesn't work if filename contains single quote, fails with: xargs: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Comment: it also files if the filename has a newline

Answer (score 54):

This could be done running a simple `find` command:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -exec mv {} PRE_{} \;
```

The above command will prefix all files and folders in the current directory with `PRE_`.

Answer (score 15):

To add a prefix to all files and folders in the current directory using util-linux's `rename` (as opposed to `prename`, the perl variant from Debian and certain other systems), you can do:

```
rename '' <prefix> *
```

This finds the first occurrence of the empty string (which is found immediately) and then replaces that occurrence with your prefix, then glues on the rest of the file name to the end of that. Done.

For *suffixes*, you need to [use the perl version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114054/3159183) or [use find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1108567/3159183).

Comment: `util-linux` on Debian Stretch seems to provide this as `/usr/bin/rename.ul`.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: This works for me `rename 's/^/some_prefix_here/' *`

Answer (score 8):

with Perl:

```
perl -e 'rename $_, "PRE_$_" for <*>'
```

Comment: This is the best way. It dealt with filenames containing newlines, single and double quotes that the other methods failed on.

Answer (score 7):

If you have Ruby(1.9+)

```
ruby -e 'Dir["*"].each{|x| File.rename(x,"PRE_"+x) }'
```

Answer (score 3):

On my system, I don't have the `rename` command. Here is a simple one liner. It finds all the HTML files recursively and adds `prefix_` in front of their names:

```
for f in $(find . -name '*.html'); do mv "$f" "$(dirname "$f")/prefix_$(basename "$f")"; done
```

Comment: with `find` you can also execute commands, no need for a loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33297439/2351568

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple script that you can use. I like using the non-standard module `File::chdir` to handle managing `cd` operations, so to use this script as-is you will need to install it (`sudo cpan File::chdir`).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;
use File::chdir; # allows cd-ing by use of $CWD, much easier but needs CPAN module

die "Usage: $0 dir prefix" unless (@ARGV >= 2);
my ($dir, $pre) = @ARGV;

opendir(my $dir_handle, $dir) or die "Cannot open directory $dir";
my @files = readdir($dir_handle);
close($dir_handle);

$CWD = $dir; # cd to the directory, needs File::chdir

foreach my $file (@files) {
  next if ($file =~ /^\.+$/); # avoid folders . and ..
  next if ($0 =~ /$file/); # avoid moving this script if it is in the directory

  move($file, $pre . $file) or warn "Cannot rename file $file: $!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will prefix your files in their directory.

The `${f%/*}` is the path till the last slash `/` -> the directory

The `${f##*/}` is the text without anything before last slash `/` -> filename without the path

So that's how it goes:

```sh
for f in $(find /directory/ -type f); do 
  mv -v $f ${f%/*}/$(date +%Y%m%d)_Prefix_${f##*/}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd and set the directory to the folder and run the following command:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b') do ren "%a" "00_%a"
```

`00_` is prefix in `"00_%a"`, so you can change it according to your requirements.
It will rename all of the files in the selected folder.