# Add file extension to files with bash

Tags: linux, bash

What is the good way to add file extension ".jpg" to extension-less files with bash?

Comment: `mv "${file}" "${file}.jpg"` ?

Comment: in your view, what is an "extension-less file"? Is it a file without a dot in the name?

Answer (score 154):

```
# Strip .jpg from all filenames
for f in *.jpg; do mv "$f" "${f%.jpg}"; done
# Add .jpg to all filenames (even those with .jpg already)
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$f.jpg"; done
# Add .jpg to all filenames...unless they are already .jpg
for f in *; do case "$f" in *.jpg) echo skipped $f;; *) mv "$f" "$f".jpg; esac; done
# Add .jpg to all filenames...unless they already have a . extension
for f in *; do case "$f" in *.*) echo skipped $f;; *) mv "$f" "$f".jpg; esac; done
```

Comment: second one is perfect for renaming extensionless files! thanks!

Comment: second one adds an extension on all files, not just extensionless ones

Comment: just as a note `"${f%.jpg}"` is bash shell string manipulation. `     
${string%substring}` Deletes shortest match of $substring from back of $string.

Comment: Warning: If you have a folder with mixed extensions, know that the above adds `.jpg` to even normal files.

Comment: Can we check if its already ended with `.jpg`? to prevent adding additional `.jpg` to the end

Answer (score 68):

You can use rename:

```
rename 's/(.*)/$1.jpg/' *
```

Comment: which version of rename are you using? Mine has different arguments: `rename from to file...`

Comment: rename is included with perl, which is version 5.10.1.

Comment: This works great with the rename included in Ubuntu (and so I'm guessing all Debian based distros), much less verbose than jm666's answer.

Comment: Beware that there isn't a single `rename` tool: https://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/12/a-tale-of-two-renames.html

Answer (score 30):

Another way - without loops

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.*" -print0 |\
xargs -0 file |\
grep  'JPEG image data' |\
sed 's/:.*//' |\
xargs -I % echo mv % %.jpg
```

Breakdown:

- find all files without extension
- check the file type
- filter out only JPG files
- delete filetype info
- xargs run the "mv" for each file

the above command is for *dry run*, after it you should remove the "echo" before mv

**EDIT**
Some people suggesting that here is needed *"Wrap path arguments in quotes; avoids argument splitting on paths with spaces"*.

Usually, this recommendation is true, in this case isn't. Because, here the `%` is got replaced **not** by shell expansion but by the `xargs` internally (directly), so the `%` will be substituted correctly even with spaces in filenames.

Simple demo:

```
$ mkdir xargstest
$ cd xargstest

# create two files with spaces in names
$ touch 'a b' 'c d'

$ find . -type f -print
./c d
./a b
# notice, here are spaces in the above paths

#the actual xargs mv WITHOUT quotes
$ find . -type f -print | xargs -I % mv % %.ext

$ find . -type f -print
./a b.ext
./c d.ext
# the result is correct even in case with spaces in the filenames...
```

Comment: You can put this into a loop and this xargs are superfluous. I like Ryan's answer better in this situation.

Comment: @Lucius - btw, the question want "extensionless" files - so Ryan should find only those...

Comment: @jm666 hey! how do I modify your code snippet to rename all extensionless files in a folder to their respective extensions. (I am detecting correct extensions by file -b $filename command.)

Answer (score 26):

Simple, 
cd to the directory where your files are and:

```
for f in *;do mv $f $f.jpg;done
```

Comment: For some reason this works for me, but Seth's solution with quotes doesn't. (OSX Mountain Lion bash)

Comment: Would be better if used `for f in *;do mv "$f" "$f".jpg;done` to support spaces in filenames.

Comment: Thanks for this elegant and simple solution -- I have landed on this answer multiple times, but can't seem to memorize it.  #dejavu

Answer (score 19):

dry run:

```
 rename -n s/$/.jpg/ *
```

actual renaming:

```
 rename s/$/.jpg/ *
```

Comment: Beware that there isn't a single `rename` tool: https://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/12/a-tale-of-two-renames.html

Answer (score 6):

```
find . | while read FILE; do if [ $(file --mime-type -b "$FILE") == "image/jpeg" ]; then mv "$FILE" "$FILE".jpg; fi; done;
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case i was not aware of the filetype so i used the ***mv*** command with the help of the ***file*** command to examine and possibly find the file type. This solution might not be perfect for all files since the ***file*** command might not recognize the filetype but it worked mostly good for me.

```
for f in *; do ext=$(file $f | awk '{print $2;}'); mv -n "$f" "$f.$ext"; done
```

The use of awk is to strip the second word of the string returned from the command ***file*** that is actually the extension.

Comment: handles jpg and png automatically. used it and works - thanks a lot! Only now extensions are CAPS. small problem though :)

Answer (score 0):

```
rename --dry-run * -a ".jpg" # test  
* -a ".jpg" # rename
```

Comment: `--dry-run` and `-a` are not available in my version of `rename`. If this is specific to some architecture it should be specified.

Comment: As @FernandoCésar alludes to, there isn't a single `rename` tool, so the syntax may vary in different systems. See https://oylenshpeegul.typepad.com/blog/2011/12/a-tale-of-two-renames.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [move multiple files](https://github.com/strogiyotec/rmf). I am a maintainer of this project. The syntax is simple.

```
mmf files*
```

It will open your $EDITOR with all files names, or vim by default and you can simply highlight the end of all file names using Ctrl+v+G in vim , save the file,quit and that it , all your files are renamed

Answer (score -3):

Ryan Li

The correct syntax for adding a file extension to multiple files within a directory which do not have a file extension is

```
find . | while read FILE; do if [[ -n `file --mime-type "$FILE" | grep 'message/rfc822'` ]]; then  mv "$FILE" "$FILE".eml; fi; done;
```