# Rename multiple files, but only rename part of the filename in Bash

Tags: bash, file-rename

I know how I can rename files and such, but I'm having trouble with this.

I only need to rename `test-this` in a for loop.

```
test-this.ext
test-this.volume001+02.ext
test-this.volume002+04.ext 
test-this.volume003+08.ext 
test-this.volume004+16.ext 
test-this.volume005+32.ext 
test-this.volume006+64.ext 
test-this.volume007+78.ext
```

Comment: Several possibilities, described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114004/add-file-extension-to-files-with-bash

Comment: This answer may also be useful: [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316038/change-part-of-the-filename-on-multiple-files-in-a-directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316038/change-part-of-the-filename-on-multiple-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 199):

If you have all of these files in one folder and you're on Linux you can use:

```
rename 's/test-this/REPLACESTRING/g' *
```

The result will be:

```
REPLACESTRING.ext
REPLACESTRING.volume001+02.ext
REPLACESTRING.volume002+04.ext
...
```

`rename` can take a command as the first argument. The command here consists of four parts:

1. `s`: flag to substitute a string with another string,
2. `test-this`: the string you want to replace,
3. `REPLACESTRING`: the string you want to replace the search string with, and
4. `g`: a flag indicating that all matches of the search string shall be replaced, i.e. if the filename is `test-this-abc-test-this.ext` the result will be `REPLACESTRING-abc-REPLACESTRING.ext`.

Refer to `man sed` for a detailed description of the flags.

Comment: Where has this command been all my life?!

Comment: This implementation of rename is version dependent, the other answer shows the same command with a different implementation syntax.

Comment: This does not work with the rename included in Fedora 25. I had to do `rename test-this REPLACESTRING *`. Anyone know which package to install in fedora to get the type of rename mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @Aditya This is Perl rename, `prename`. On Fedora, I believe the package is just called `prename`.

Comment: can I have the answer for macOS? it says `zsh: command not found: rename`

Comment: This worked great. I just installed the `rename` package, and puff, I was able to rename all my files.

Comment: Note the `-n` flag which lets you dry run it ahead of time (there is no undo :).

Comment: @Dylan `brew install rename`

Comment: On Ubuntu I did have to do this: `rename.ul '.html' '.html.erb' ./*.html` - note "rename.ul", and passing 3 arguments (regex, replacement and list of files) instead of just a substring in this answer.

Comment: That's why all the other comments here already explain that the one you are using is the utility in the other `rename` answer.

Comment: I needed to do `sudo apt-get install rename` on a Ubuntu 18 machine. I was using `mv` earlier and that didn't help with multiple files. `rename` did

Answer (score 82):

Use `rename` as shown below:

```
rename test-this foo test-this*
```

This will replace `test-this` with `foo` in the file names.

If you don't have `rename` use a `for` loop as shown below:

```
for i in test-this*
do
    mv "$i" "${i/test-this/foo}"
done
```

Comment: Note this is the [util-linux `rename`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), not the Perl `rename` mentioned in another answer.

Comment: This seems to the be rename command that is included with my Centos distro. Apparently the other rename is not universal to Linux.

Comment: Neither of them is universal. That's why we need two separate answers. Probably the answer itself should be more explicit and detailed about this.

Answer (score 31):

#### Function

I'm on OSX and my bash doesn't come with `rename` as a built-in function. I create a function in my `.bash_profile` that takes the first argument, which is a pattern in the file that should only match once, and doesn't care what comes after it, and replaces with the text of argument 2.

```
rename() {
    for i in $1*
    do
        mv "$i" "${i/$1/$2}"
    done
}
```

#### Input Files

```
test-this.ext
test-this.volume001+02.ext
test-this.volume002+04.ext 
test-this.volume003+08.ext 
test-this.volume004+16.ext 
test-this.volume005+32.ext 
test-this.volume006+64.ext 
test-this.volume007+78.ext
```

#### Command

```
rename test-this hello-there
```

#### Output

```
hello-there.ext
hello-there.volume001+02.ext
hello-there.volume002+04.ext 
hello-there.volume003+08.ext 
hello-there.volume004+16.ext 
hello-there.volume005+32.ext 
hello-there.volume006+64.ext 
hello-there.volume007+78.ext
```

Comment: If you have Homebrew, you can install `rename` with `brew install rename`

Comment: the `for i in $1*` syntax should generally be avoided as it will break on paths with spaces, stars, quotes and other funny characters; `find . -iname "$1" -exec sh -c 'do work here' {} \;` is more reliable since it will handle correctly any paths.

Comment: Works great, also in Cygwin.

Answer (score 16):

Without using `rename`:

```
find -name test-this\*.ext | sed 'p;s/test-this/replace-that/' | xargs -d '\n' -n 2 mv
```

The way it works is as follows:

1. `find` will, well, find all files matching your criteria. If you pass `-name` a glob expression, don't forget to escape the `*`.
2. Pipe the newline-separated* list of filenames into `sed`, which will:

   a. Print (`p`) one line.

   b. Substitute (`s///`) `test-this` with `replace-that` and print the result.

   c. Move on to the next line.
3. Pipe the newline-separated list of alternating old and new filenames to `xargs`, which will:

   a. Treat newlines as delimiters (`-d '\n'`).

   b. Call `mv` repeatedly with up to 2 (`-n 2`) arguments each time.

For a dry run, try the following:

```
find -name test-this\*.ext | sed 'p;s/test-this/replace-that/' | xargs -d '\n' -n 2 echo mv
```

*: Keep in mind it won't work if your filenames include newlines.

Comment: This answer is the UNIX way.   This answer applies to an unfathomable number of applications and will support skipping over the clouds like a UNIX GOD.   The rename answer is a one-off.

Answer (score 1):

to rename index.htm to index.html

```
rename [what you want to rename] [what you want it to be] [match on these files]
rename .htm .HTML *.htm
```

renames index.htm to index.html
It will do this for all files that match *.htm in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont understand `xargs` well enough to feel comfortable doing this, try this:

```
for i in your_files_*
do
    mv $i ${i/your_files_/new_prefix_}
    # Use `echo ${i/your_files_/new_prefix_}` here first to confirm you got the pattern right
done
```

Answer (score -2):

thx for your passion and answers. I also find a solution for me to rename multiple files on my linux terminal and directly add a little counter. With this I have a very good chance to have better SEO names.

Here is the command

```
count=1 ; zmv '(*).jpg' 'new-seo-name--$((count++)).jpg'
```

I also do a live coding video and publush it to [YouTube](https://youtu.be/JCCcBZVSXYo)