# Changing multiple filenames that with a number already in the file name in Unix

Tags: unix, file-rename

so I want to batch change name files with these type of names (about 400 files):

```
L1_Mviridis.fasta
L2_Mviridis.fasta
L3_Mviridis.fasta...
```

to this:

```
L1_1_Mviridis.fasta
L2_2_Mviridis.fasta
L3_3_Mviridis.fasta
```

I do not have the function "rename" available either.
Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices I suggest you can write a python script to rename each file first you `split()` function to split the underscore and extract the number the question is not that clear

[Rename multiple files in a directory in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759067/rename-multiple-files-in-a-directory-in-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

there is already an answer here also

Or you can use the `mv` command to rename `mv <old name> <new name>` and write a bash script to rename each one you can use `sed` or `awk` to rename each file

you can chain command for example ls -la | awk  you can use for loop to iterate ls -l below is the guide to shell scripting

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html

there is already an answer here
[BASH: Rename multiple files. But only rename part of the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657432/bash-rename-multiple-files-but-only-rename-part-of-the-filename?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I hope this is a good starting point to you