# Remove part of filename for multiple files using bash

Tags: bash, sh

I have multiple files named
`01 - a.txt`, `02 - b.txt`, `03 - c.txt` etc. I want to remove the initial number and the dash to have all files named like `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`. I'm not good with bash so I would be extremely thankful for some help.

Many thanks!

Comment: This has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657432/rename-multiple-files-but-only-rename-part-of-the-filename-in-bash) already

Comment: Not exactly, since this requires a for loop and a conversion of integer to string I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [substring removal](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) `##*-`

E.g.

```
$ arr=("01 - a.txt" "02 - b.txt" "03 - c.txt")

$ echo "${arr[@]##*- }"
a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

In a loop

```
for i in *-*.txt;do echo "$i" "${i##*- }";done
01 - a.txt a.txt
02 - b.txt b.txt
03 - c.txt c.txt
```

Replace `echo` with `mv` if the output looks ok.