# Changing name to files in bash respecting the number associated to each file

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files in bash named `myfile1.sh`, `myfile2.sh`, `myfile3.sh`... and so on. I would like to **remove** the `sh` part in each one of them, that is: rename to `myfile1`, `myfile2`, `myfile3`, ... Do you have a suggestion to do it all at once?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add file extension to files with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114004/add-file-extension-to-files-with-bash)

Comment: The first line of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6114049/8344060) is what you are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `rename` command, you can use it:

```
rename 's/\.sh$//' *.sh
```

A bash one-liner can be:

```
for f in *.sh; do mv "$f" "${f%.sh}"; done
```

Comment: Rather than removing the first instance of `.sh` from the file, it would make more sense to remove it from the end using `"${f%.sh}"`

Comment: Or you could add the `%` anchor to your substitution: `${file/%.sh}`.

Comment: @TomFenech That's indeed better. Thanks.

Comment: YIKES!!!! Don't do that!!!! The dot matches anything including `A`... try `touch GreyAshenTiles.txt` and running the command with the `--dry-run` option. At the very least use `s/.sh$//`, preferably `s/\.sh$//` and don't wildcard at the end, just use `rename ... *.sh`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in *.sh; do mv "$i" "${i%.sh}"; done
```