# Batch convert all files with unknown extension in directory

Tags: command-line, terminal, rename

Some how I have image files as `Texteditor - documents` with no extension. Can I use the command tool `rename` to change all the files in `*.jpg`? Using terminal on mac.

Something like `rename *.* *.jpg` or `rename . *.jpg` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114004/add-file-extension-to-files-with-bash).

cd to the directory/folder the files are in preferably an images folders because this works on **EVERYTHING** without an extension including folders and adds to other extensions like .json (file extension will become .json.jpg) or another .jpg (file extension will become .jpg.jpg:

`for f in *;do mv $f $f.jpg;done`

I work on a Mac as well and I actually had this question bookmarked. I tried it out to make sure it still works in terminal and it does.

Comment: The person that answered this question is [bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6440463/bharath).