# Add prefix to all images (recursive)

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I have a folder with more than 5000 images, all with JPG extension.

What i want to do, is to add recursively the "thumb_" prefix to all images.

I found a similar question: [Rename Files and Directories (Add Prefix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787413/rename-files-and-directories-add-prefix)   but i only want to add the prefix to files with the JPG extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename Files and Directories (Add Prefix)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787413/rename-files-and-directories-add-prefix), just replace `'*'` with `'*.jpg'`.

Comment: no it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

One of possibly solutions:

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -printf "'%p' '%h/thumb_%f'\n" | xargs -n2  echo mv
```

Principe: find all needed files, and prepare arguments for the standard `mv` command.

Notes:

- arguments for the `mv` are surrounded by `'` for allowing spaces in filenames.
- The drawback is: this will not works with filenames what are containing `'` apostrophe itself, like many mp3 files. If you need moving *more strange* filenames check bellow.
- the above command is for **dry run** (only shows the mv commands with args). For real work remove the `echo` pretending `mv`.

ANY filename renaming. In the shell you need a delimiter. The problem is, than the filename  (stored in a shell variable) usually **can** contain the delimiter itself, so:

```
mv $file $newfile         #will fail, if the filename contains space, TAB or newline
mv "$file" "$newfile"     #will fail, if the any of the filenames contains "
```

the correct solution are either:

- prepare a filename with a proper escaping
- use a scripting language what easuly understands ANY filename

Preparing the correct escaping in *bash* is possible with it's internal `printf` and `%q` formatting directive = `print quoted`. But this solution is long and boring.

IMHO, the easiest way is using `perl` and zero padded `print0`, like next.

```
find . -name \*.jpg -print0 | perl -MFile::Basename -0nle 'rename $_, dirname($_)."/thumb_".basename($_)'
```

The above using perl's power to mungle the filenames and finally renames the files.

Answer (score 3):

Beware of filenames with spaces in (the `for ... in ...` expression trips over those), and be aware that the result of a `find . ...` will always start with `./` (and hence try to give you names like `thumb_./file.JPG` which isn't quite correct).

This is therefore not a trivial thing to get right under all circumstances. The expression I've found to work correctly (with spaces, subdirs and all that) is:

```
find . -iname \*.JPG -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "`echo $1 | sed \"s/\(.*\)\//\1\/thumb/\"`"' -- '{}' \;
```

Even that can fall foul of certain names (with quotes in) ...

Answer (score 3):

In OS X 10.8.5, find does not have the -printf option. The port that contained rename seemed to depend upon a WebkitGTK development package that was taking hours to install.

This one line, recursive file rename script worked for me:

```
find . -iname "*.jpg"  -print | while read name; do cur_dir=$(dirname "$name"); cur_file=$(basename "$name"); mv "$name" "$cur_dir/thumb_$cur_file"; done
```

I was actually renaming CakePHP view files with an 'admin_' prefix, to move them all to an admin section.

Comment: You can always install the `findutils` macport - what contains a gnu-find (command: `gfind`) with `-printf`.

Comment: Just noting that I got a file not found error for every line, but it worked as promised

Answer (score 2):

You can use that same answer, just use `*.jpg`, instead of just `*`.

Answer (score 1):

`for file in *.JPG; do mv $file thumb_$file; done`

if it's multiple directory levels under the current one:

`for file in $(find . -name '*.JPG'); do mv $file $(dirname $file)/thumb_$(basename $file); done`

---

proof:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ mkdir test test/a test/a/b test/a/b/c
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ touch test/a/A.JPG test/a/b/B.JPG test/a/b/c/C.JPG
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cd test
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp/test$ for file in $(find . -name '*.JPG'); do mv $file $(dirname $file)/thumb_$(basename $file); done
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp/test$ find .
.
./a
./a/b
./a/b/thumb_B.JPG
./a/b/c
./a/b/c/thumb_C.JPG
./a/thumb_A.JPG
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp/test$
```

Comment: As said in ref. question's answers, you need to consider file names with spaces.

Comment: @MadisonFord If your files have an extension of .jpg instead of .JPG this will not work on a normal linux environment. Bash is case sensitive, normally. `shopt -s nocaseglob` will turn off case sensitivity.

Comment: @MadisonFord, are spaces in filenames a problem in your case? and which command did you paste?

Answer (score 1):

Use `rename` for this:

```
rename 's/(\w{1})\.JPG$/thumb_$1\.JPG/' `find . -type f -name *.JPG`
```

Answer (score -1):

For only `jpg` files in current folder

```
for f in `ls *.jpg` ; do mv "$f" "PRE_$f" ; done
```

Comment: I need to do it in all folders (recursive) i have more than 300 folders with more than 5000 images.

Comment: That's wrong. Almost never parse the output of `ls`. Try a file `touch "a b c.jpg"` Instead, `for f in *.jpg` is much, much better.

Comment: Use @jcomeau_ictx's answer, just put `""` while moving file.