# Rename the beginning of file recursively

Tags: linux, find, rename

Im trying to rename all .avi files recursively which start with "." to not starting with a dot. So

```
.04-03-29_15-00.00.avi  .04-03-31_17-54.00.avi
.04-03-25_00-09.00.avi  .04-03-25_20-28.00.avi
```

should become

```
04-03-29_15-00.00.avi  04-03-31_17-54.00.avi
04-03-25_00-09.00.avi  04-03-25_20-28.00.avi
```

Im experimenting with this commmand, but i cant get it working, the error ist `rename: not enough arguments`

```
find . -name "*.avi" -exec rename -n 's/^\.*/\/i' *avi {} \;
```

Comment: [Rename all files in a folder with a prefix in a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6329505/608639), [Add prefix to all images (recursive)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6140134/608639), [Find and replace filename recursively in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9393607/608639), [Bulk rename, change prefix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/47367), [Recursively rename all files whose name starts with a dash](https://askubuntu.com/q/882773) and friends.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with:

```
find . -name '*.avi' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1/\/.//}"' -- {} \;
```