# Rename all files in a folder with a prefix in a single command

Tags: linux, unix, rename

Rename all the files within a folder with prefix `"Unix_"`

Suppose a folder has two files

```
a.txt
b.pdf
```

then they both should be renamed from a single command to

```
Unix_a.txt
Unix_b.pdf
```

Comment: check this link => http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/bulk-renaming-of-files-in-unix.html

Comment: fast and easy: `rename '' <prefix> *`

Answer (score 143):

If your filenames contain **no whitepace** and you don't have any subdirectories, you can use a simple `for` loop:

```
$ for FILENAME in *; do mv $FILENAME Unix_$FILENAME; done
```

Otherwise use the convenient `rename` command (which is a perl script) - although it might not be available out of the box on every Unix (e.g. OS X doesn't come with `rename`).

A short overview at debian-administration.org:

- [Easily renaming multiple files](http://web.archive.org/web/20160319034832/http://www.debian-administration.org/article/150/Easily_renaming_multiple_files.)

If your filenames contain whitespace it's easier to use `find`, on Linux the following should work:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*' -printf "echo mv '%h/%f' '%h/Unix_%f\n'" | sh
```

On BSD systems, there is no `-printf` option, unfortunately. But [GNU findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) should be installable (on e.g. Mac OS X with `brew install findutils`).

```
$ gfind . -type f -name '*' -printf "mv \"%h/%f\" \"%h/Unix_%f\"\n" | sh
```

Comment: @Matteo: Thanks the hint: updated my answer with a warning plus two examples with `find`.

Comment: Also would recommend `for f in *; do [[ -f ${f} ]] && mv ...; done` to catch only files (no sub-directories, links, etc.)...

Comment: If you quote variables as you should, then `for FILENAME in *; do mv "$FILENAME" "Unix_$FILENAME"; done` works correctly regardless of what characters are in the file names.  It does move directories, sockets, symlinks and other file types too; I presume that doesn't matter.

Comment: Somehow this added a `.` before all my files

Comment: as of March 2022, the link to debian-administration.org doesn't work.

Comment: @DrPhil, Wayback Machine to the rescue.

Answer (score 93):

Try the `rename` command *in the folder with the files*:

```
rename 's/^/Unix_/' *
```

The argument of rename ([sed s command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command)) indicates to replace the regex *^* with *Unix_*. The caret (^) is a special character that means *start of the line*.

Comment: Could you explain what `'s/^/.../'` means?

Comment: @Matteo `'s/^/.../'` is the perl expression argument for the [rename command](http://www.tecmint.com/rename-multiple-files-in-linux/)

Comment: this is awesome! i'd suggest to add folder/* , because * is a bit dangerous if command accidently will be repeated in another place

Comment: brew install rename @OliverPearmain

Comment: Example to replace a prefix: `rename 's/^start_/run_' *`

Comment: Based on your Linux distribution you may want to try to install `rename`, `prename` or `perl-rename` packages (they all work the same way)

Comment: Requires installing ```rename``` package in linux

Comment: `man rename` says that you can use `-v` and `-n` to check what will be done without actually doing anything. That helps me a lot.

Answer (score 49):

I think this is just what you'er looking for:

```
ls | xargs -I {} mv {} Unix_{}
```

Yes, it is simple yet elegant and powerful, and also one-liner.
You can get more detailed intro from me on the page:[Rename Files and Directories (Add Prefix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787413/rename-files-and-directories-add-prefix/13760038)

Comment: Beware of processing the output of `ls` — it can lead to problems if there are spaces or other oddball characters in the file names.

Comment: is it possible to replace certain chracter(s) while renaming. For example, if the file name is 2.0.2.CR1.zip, it should become 2.0.2.GA.zip

Answer (score 22):

I recently faced this same situation and found an easier inbuilt solution. I am sharing it here so that it might help other people looking for solution.

With OS X Yosemite, Apple has integrated the batch renaming capabilities directly into Finder. Details information is available [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19067?locale=en_US). I have copied the steps below as well,

**Rename multiple items**

1. Select the items, then Control-click one of them.
2. In the shortcut menu, select Rename Items.
3. In the pop-up menu below Rename Folder Items, choose to replace text in the names, add text to the names, or change the name format.

   - Replace text: Enter the text you want to remove in the Find field, then enter the text you want to add in the “Replace with” field.
   - Add text: Enter the text to you want to add in the field, then choose to add the text before or after the current name.
   - Format: Choose a name format for the files, then choose to put the index, counter, or date before or after the name. Enter a name in the Custom Format field, then enter the number you want to start with.
4. Click Rename.

If you have a common pattern in your files than you can use Replace text otherwise Add text would also do the job.

Comment: Excellent - saved me a lot of time!

Comment: Great solution for Mac users

Answer (score 7):

You can just use `-i` instead of `-I {}`

```
ls | xargs -i mv {} unix_{}
```

This also works perfectly.

- `ls` - lists all the files in the directory
- `xargs` - accepts all files line by line due to the `-i` option
- `{}` is the placeholder for all files, necessary if `xargs` gets more than two arguments as input

Using awk:

```
ls -lrt | grep '^-' | awk '{print "mv "$9" unix_"$9""}' | sh
```

Comment: `-i` is deprecated, now is just `-I`

Comment: it's helped me on Debian 8.Thaks

Answer (score 2):

Also works for items with spaces and ignores directories

```
for f in *; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && mv "$f" "unix_$f"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

With [rnm](https://github.com/neurobin/rnm) (you will need to install it):

```
rnm -ns 'Unix_/fn/' *
```

Or

```
rnm -rs '/^/Unix_/' *
```

P.S : I am the author of this tool.

Comment: You should go through all your answers about your utility, and add the disclaimer that you are its author.

Comment: @Mogsdad : I don't think its that of a necessary info. If someone wants to find the author, it's pretty easy.

Comment: Thank you for this tool. For some reason, `rename` doesn't work for me, but `rnm` does.

Answer (score 1):

**Situation:**

We have `certificate.key` `certificate.crt` inside `/user/ssl/`

We want to rename anything that starts with `certificate` to `certificate_OLD`

We are now located inside `/user`

First, you do a dry run with `-n`:

`rename -n "s/certificate/certificate_old/" ./ssl/*`

Which returns:

`rename(./ssl/certificate.crt, ./ssl/certificate_OLD.crt)
 rename(./ssl/certificate.key, ./ssl/certificate_OLD.key)`

Your files will be unchanged this is just a test run.

**Solution:**

When your happy with the result of the test run it for real:

`rename "s/certificate/certificate_OLD/" ./ssl/*`

What it means:

`rename "s/ SOMETHING / SOMETING_ELSE " PATH/FILES

**Tip:**

If you are already on the path run it like this:

`rename "s/certificate/certificate_OLD/" *`

Or if you want to do this in any sub-directory starting with `ss` do:

`rename -n "s/certificat/certificate_old/" ./ss*/*`

You can also do:

`rename -n "s/certi*/certificate_old/" ./ss*/*`

Which renames anything starting with `certi` in any sub-directory starting with `ss`.

The sky is the limit.

Play around with regex and ALWAYS test this BEFORE with `-n`.

WATCH OUT THIS WILL EVEN RENAME FOLDER NAMES THAT MATCH.
Better `cd` into the directory and do it there. 
USE AT OWN RISK.

Answer (score -1):

**`find -execdir rename`**

This renames files and directories with a regular expression affecting only basenames.

So for a prefix you could do:

```
PATH=/usr/bin find . -depth -execdir rename 's/^/Unix_/' '{}' \;
```

or to affect files only:

```
PATH=/usr/bin find . -type f -execdir rename 's/^/Unix_/' '{}' \;
```

`-execdir` first `cd`s into the directory before executing only on the basename.

I have explained it in more detail at: [Find multiple files and rename them in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/find-multiple-files-and-rename-them-in-linux/54163971#54163971)