# How to add text to the beginning of all files in a folder?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I have a folder with 1,000 small text files in it, and I need to modify the files and add 7 zeroes to the beginning of every one. After I do this I'll be able to cat them all together. Is there an easy way to do this in terminal?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329505/how-to-rename-all-file-in-a-folder-with-a-suffix-in-a-single-unix-command) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Snowsickle No, I don't need to change the name, just the contents.

Comment: Are there any other files in that folder?

Comment: @Beta Nothing other than the text files that I need to edit.

Comment: Related (even duplicate): http://askubuntu.com/questions/11031/add-a-string-to-a-text-file-from-terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Find all files in the current directory and insert `0000000` at the beginning of the file using `sed`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i.bk '1i \
0000000' {} \;
```

This will also create `.bk` file for each file in directory. If you are happy with the result just `rm *.bk` to delete the back up files.

Comment: Didn't work; gave 'invalid command code'.

Comment: Not `-i` but `-e` or better nothing (just `sed '1 i'`)

Comment: Tested on Linux not Mac, edited to make Mac friendly. @GoZoner no, `-i`.

Comment: @sudo_O Anyway to get the zeros on the same line as the text? Sorry, in a bit over my head here :)

Answer (score 4):

Paste this in a .sh file and execute it. Put the path to your file directory instead of the example one.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="./files/*"

for f in $FILES
do
    echo '0000000' | cat - $f > temp && mv temp $f
done
```