# Hadoop Rename command

Tags: hadoop, command, hdfs

How to rename multiple files in HDFS

200 files are present under directory **/warehouse/bigdata/data**, I want to append **"_d"** in all file name

Is there any way to do it in one go?

For Example: **/warehouse/bigdata/data/test** to **/warehouse/bigdata/data/test_d**

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can not rename a directory of file in hadoop/HDFS

but you can do :

```
Hadoop fs -mv /warehouse/bigdata/data/test /warehouse/bigdata/data/test_d
```

If you want to do this for all your 200 HDFS part files then you have to write Shell/bash script to do this in recursive loop.

just write above hadoop command in shell loop.

follow this: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/renaming-multiple-files-at-a-shell-prompt.html

and this [how to rename all file in a folder with a prefix in a single unix command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329505/how-to-rename-all-file-in-a-folder-with-a-prefix-in-a-single-unix-command)