# Multiple files rename using linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have following images.

```
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpg
```

I want to remove above images. I used following shell script file.

```
for file in /home/scrapping/imgs/*
do
    COUNT=$(expr $COUNT + 1)
    STRING="/home/scrapping/imgs/""Img_"$COUNT".jpg"
    echo $STRING
    mv "$file" "$STRING"
done
```

So, replaced file name

```
Img_1.jpg
Img_2.jpg
Img_3.jpg
```

But, I want to replace the file name like this:

```
Img_10.jpg
Img_11.jpg
Img_12.jpg
```

So, How to set `COUNT` value 10 to get my own output?

Comment: Pre-assign 10 to the count?

Comment: Initialize the variable `count` before `for`

Comment: @ValdeirPsr I have initialized but not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename all files in a folder with a prefix in a single unix command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329505/rename-all-files-in-a-folder-with-a-prefix-in-a-single-unix-command)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `expr` syntax is pretty outdated, POSIX shell allows you to do arithmetic evaluation with `$(())` syntax. You can just do

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

count=10
for file in /home/scrapping/imgs/*; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    mv "$file" "/home/scrapping/imgs/Img_$((count++)).jpg"
done
```

Also from the errors reported in the comments, you seem to be running it from the `dash` shell. It does not seem to have all the features complying to the standard POSIX shell. Run it with the `sh` or the `bash` shell.

And always use lowercase letters for user defined variables in your shell script. Upper case letters are primarily for the environment variables managed by the shell itself.

Answer (score 1):

With rename command you can suffix your files with *Img_*:

```
rename 's/^/Img_/' *
```

The *^* means replace the start of the filename with *Img_*, i.e: adds a suffix.