# find all files with no .mov extention and add .mov

Tags: bash, file, shell, command-line, file-extension

I've been using this post as a reference ([recursively add file extension to all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108527/recursively-add-file-extension-to-all-files)) and it has gotten me 90% of the way where I want to be but I'm lost on how to complete the shell script I need.

Here is my script I've made so far:

```
find /Users/Floyd/Desktop/test -type f -not -name "*.*" -not -ipath "*zworkfolder*" -exec mv '{}' '{}'.mov \;
```

I want to find all files in the folder "test" that do not have a .mov extension and add the extension to the end of the filename.  For the most part it works but I run into a problem when I come up against filenames that have a "." in the filename.
Ex. "A020_C020_0321R7_001_A020_C020_0321R7_001.new.02".

What can I do to make it add a .mov extension to these filenames?

Thank you.

Floyd.

Comment: Do you mean "files that don't have a .mov extension", or "files that don't have an extension"? Or something else? `-not -name "*.*"` will eliminate any file with an extension (i.e. which has a dot somewhere in the filename). If you didn't want that, don't put it in the command.

Comment: Isn't `-not -name "*.mov"`  what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want files matching `*.mov`, you should filter by that, rather than the more generic `*.*`..
thus the following should do the trick:

```
  find /Users/Floyd/Desktop/test \
       -type f -not -name "*.mov" -not -ipath "*zworkfolder*" \
       -exec mv \{\} \{\}.mov \;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Easy question, easy answer.  It works now.  Thought I had tried that last night but I was tired so who knows.  Thanks again.