# Changing all file's extensions in a folder using CLI in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

How to change all file's extensions in a folder using one command on CLI in Linux?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `rename`:

`rename 's/.old$/.new/' *.old`

Comment: The above did not work for me. But this worked for me.
>>rename .htm .html *.htm

Answer (score 5):

If you have the perl `rename` installed (there are different `rename` implementations) you can do something like this:

```
$ ls -1
test1.foo
test2.foo
test3.foo

$ rename 's/\.foo$/.bar/' *.foo

$ ls -1
test1.bar
test2.bar
test3.bar
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a for-loop on the command line:

```
for foo in *.old; do mv $foo `basename $foo .old`.new; done
```

this will take all files with extension .old and rename them to .new

Answer (score 4):

This should works on current directory **AND** sub-directories. It will rename all ***.oldExtension*** files under directory structure with a new extension.

```
for f in `find . -iname '*.oldExtension' -type f -print`;do mv "$f" ${f%.oldExtension}.newExtension; done
```

Comment: The second arg should be wrapped with `"` (cannot edit: "too many pending edits" issue).

Answer (score 1):

This will work recursively, and with files containing spaces.
Be sure to replace `.old` and `.new` with the proper extensions before running.

`find . -iname '*.old' -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.old}.new"' {} \;`

Answer (score -2):

Source : [recursively add file extension to all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108527/recursively-add-file-extension-to-all-files)
(Not my answer.)

> `find . -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.jpg \;`

Explanation: this recursively finds all files (-type f) starting from the current directory (.) and applies the move command (mv) to each of them. Note also the quotes around {}, so that filenames with spaces (and even newlines...) are properly handled.

Comment: Actually this does not remove the old extension, but rather appends the new extension.